# Outer class unable to access a method's local variable

Tags: java

I am drawing different shapes within a JPanel using paintComponent method and counting the number of iterations for each type of shape (i.e. rectangle and oval).  I would like my instance variable to access this shape count variable being incremented within the paintComponent method, but can't figure out why the instance variable "countRectangle1" is not copying the method's local variable "countRectangle"--

```
package ch8ex8p1;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawShape extends JPanel
{
private SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private Color color;
private int countRectangle1; //this will copy countRectangle after iteration 
private int countOval1;


public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    int width = getWidth(); //total width
    int height = getHeight(); //total height
    int coordinate1;
    int coordinate2;
    int countRectangle = 0; //counts number of times a Rectangle is drawn


    for (int counter = 0; counter <=10; counter++ )
    {
        //generate numbers to use for x and width
        coordinate1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(width);
        coordinate2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(width);

        while (coordinate1 == coordinate2)
            coordinate2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(width);

        //identify x and width
        if (coordinate1 > coordinate2)
        {
            this.width = coordinate1;
            this.x = coordinate2;
        }
        else
        {
            this.width = coordinate2;
            this.x = coordinate1;
        }

        //generate numbers to use for y and height
        coordinate1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(height);
        coordinate2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(height);
        while (coordinate1 == coordinate2)
            coordinate2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(height);

        //identify y and height
        if (coordinate1 > coordinate2)
        {
            this.height = coordinate1;
            this.y = coordinate2;
        }
        else
        {
            this.height = coordinate2;
            this.y = coordinate1;
        }

        //generate random color for the shapes
        Color color = new Color(randomNumbers.nextInt(256), randomNumbers.nextInt(256),
                randomNumbers.nextInt(256));
        this.color = color;

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //draw random shape
        int drawFlag = randomNumbers.nextInt(2);
        if (drawFlag==0)
        {
            MyRect myRectangle = new MyRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height
                    , this.color);
            myRectangle.draw(g);
            setCount(1);
            countRectangle++;
        }
        else
        {
            MyOval myOval = new MyOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height
                    , this.color);
            myOval.draw(g);

        }

    }//end for loop


    //assign count to outer variable
    this.countRectangle1 = countRectangle;
    //setCount(countRectangle);
    System.out.print("\ncount Rectangle: " + countRectangle1);

}//end painComponent

public void setCount(int count)
{
    countRectangle1 = countRectangle1 + count;
}

public int getCount()
{
    return countRectangle1;
}
}//end class
```

I've tried using setters and getters but it doesn't work.  I've also tried changing the class's variable to "protected", but it still doesn't work.  It seems that when paintComponent is done, the count resets back to 0.  I've added "this" to the class variable when assigning the value and it's still not getting the right output.  Within paintComponent, it seems to get the count but when it's outside of paintComponent, it becomes 0.

Here is the class that calls the count, but is getting 0:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawShapeTest extends JFrame 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DrawShape shape = new DrawShape();
    JFrame app = new JFrame();
    app.setSize(400, 400);

    JLabel rectangleLabel = new JLabel();
    //rectangleLabel.setText("aaaarrrrrgghhhh!!!!!" + shape.getCount());
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    shape.setSize(300, 300);
    System.out.println("\nsecond print Rectangle: " + shape.getCount());
    app.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    app.add(shape);
    app.add(rectangleLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    app.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Appreciate any help.  The supposed second print line for Rectangle count is displaying 0, and is actually printing prior to the for loop under Draw Shape Class (where the shapes are generated) so it seems my code is out of sequence, and I'm currently still trying to figure it out.

Comment: "*... within the inner class ...*" - I do not see any inner class, neither static, non-static, nor anonymous. All in all, I have a hard time to understand, what you are trying to achieve. The fact that you have an attribute `countRectangle1` and a local variable `countRectangle` does not help either. Can you rephrase your explanation? Also what "*does not work*" mean? Did your attempts not compile? Did they throw `Exception`s? Please be precise.

Comment: @Turing85 Hi, thanks for the response.  I actually meant method instead of inner class, I apologize.  I've also edited my description.  The instance variable, countRectangle1 is not getting the number of iterations within paintComponent, being captured by paintComponent's local variable, countRectangle.

Comment: Please provide code where you access the `countRectangle1`. I am pretty sure your `System.out.print("\ncount Rectangle: " + countRectangle1);` print the correct value

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn Thanks for the response.  I've added the code at the top, and updated the problem description.  It seems that my code is out of sequence, and I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Call `System.out.println("\nsecond print Rectangle: " + shape.getCount());` after `app.setVisible(true);`

The problem is you're accessing the variable before its value is assigned because function `paintComponent()` does not run until it start painting. (visible)

**Edit**
To start JFrame app, put this into your main method

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame();
             //bla bla....
           frame.setVisible(true);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's generating the same output :/

Comment: Is this statement `System.out.print("\ncount Rectangle: " + countRectangle1);` print out anything?

Comment: I think it will not print anything because you're not start  your app yet

Comment: It did print..

The output is

>>second print Rectangle: 2

>>first count Rectangle: 5
>>first count Rectangle: 7  

looks like second print line is being performed first which, supposedly comes after paintComponent method has been called.  Even if I move the second print line after setvisible or adding the panel to the frame, it still comes first

Comment: I removed all the iteration to simplify the code and it seems that the behavior for accessing the variables is the same.  System.out print line on the JFrame class comes first..